# Can Peano arithmetic be completed using only atomic $\omega$-completions?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, incompleteness

Say we have an axiomatizable theory $T$ extending $Th(A_E)$ where $A_E$ are the axioms of arithmetic. What I call an atomic $\omega$-completion of $T$ (I am not sure if there is a more standard terminology) is a theory of the form $T\cup \lbrace \forall n \phi(n) \rbrace$, where $\phi$ is a formula in one variable such that $T$ proves $\phi(n)$ for every $n\in{\mathbb N}$.

**Question.** Is there a sequence $(T_n)_{n\geq 1}$ of theories such that for every $n$, $T_{n+1}$ is an atomic $\omega$-completion of $T_n$ and $T_{\infty}=\bigcup_{n\geq 1}T_n$ is a complete theory ?

We assume that Peano arithmetic is consistent, of course, so that each $T_n$ in the sequence will be consistent also.

My thoughts : There might be a formula $\phi$ in two variables such that $T$ proves $\phi(n,m)$ for every $n,m\in {\mathbb N}^2$ but such that $T$ does not prove $\psi_n : \forall m \phi(n,m)$ for any $n$, so that to extend $T$ to a theory that proves $\forall n \psi_n$ we would seem to need an infinite number of statements first, namely all the $\psi_n$'s.

Comment: Do you want your $T$ to be *correct* as well as axiomatizable and consistent? If you don't, it's not generally true that an atomic $\omega$-completion of $T$ need be consistent: take e.g. $T=\mathsf{PA}+\neg \mathsf{Con(PA)}$. If you do, then your question amounts to whether we can get true arithmetic by a length-$\omega$ sequence of applications of the $\omega$-rule, and the answer to this is **negative** for general computability-theoretic reasons: the set of all sentences you can get into some $T_n$ is arithmetic (specifically $\Sigma^0_3$ at a glance).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Unless I missed something, the whole point about atomic $\omega$-completion is that (when the base theory is consistent) it can go in one direction only. Thus (assuming PA is consistent), PA proves that "PA does not prove 0=1 in less than $n$ steps" for every $n$. Thus $PA+Con(PA)$ is an atomic $\omega$-completion, but $PA+\neg Con(PA)$ is not (unless you can perhaps transform $\neg Con(PA)$ into an equivalent statement which gives an atomic $\omega$-completion).

Comment: I'm talking about the **starting** theory $T$: $\mathsf{PA}+\neg \mathsf{Con(PA)}+ \mathsf{Con(PA)}$ is an atomic $\omega$-completion of $\mathsf{PA}+\neg\mathsf{Con(PA)}$, and is inconsistent even though the latter is consistent. So your initial $T$ (or $T_1$ I suppose) should probably be assumed to be sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume our starting theory $T$ is **sound** (= a subtheory of true arithmetic $\mathsf{TA}$). Otherwise, atomic $\omega$-completions need not preserve consistency: $\mathsf{PA}+\neg\mathsf{Con(PA)}+\mathsf{Con(PA)}$ is an inconsistent atomic $\omega$-completion of the consistent theory $\mathsf{PA}+\neg\mathsf{Con(PA)}$.

Say that a sentence $\varphi$ is **reachable** from a fixed c.e. theory $T$ iff there is some finite sequence of successive atomic $\omega$-completions starting with $T$ which results in a theory containing $\varphi$. The set of reachable sentences is $\Sigma^0_3$ since $\varphi$ is reachable iff there is some finite sequence $(\psi_i(x))_{1\le i\le n}$ of formulas such that $$T\cup\{\forall x\psi_i(x): 1\le i\le n\}\vdash\varphi$$ and for each $i$ and each $k\in\omega$ we have $$T\cup\{\forall x\psi_j(x): j<i\}\vdash \psi_i(\underline{k}).$$ Since true arithmetic is not arithmetic (per Tarski), this means that the set of reachable sentences is not just true arithmetic. But since we started with a subtheory of true arithmetic and the $\omega$-rule is sound, every reachable sentence is true in $\mathbb{N}$. So the set of reachable sentences is not complete.

---

Note, however, that we can continue this process transfinitely. When we do this, we do in fact wind up with true arithmetic after $\omega^2$-many steps, as long as we start with something reasonably strong (e.g. $\mathsf{PA}$ or even Robinson's $\mathsf{Q}$). Basically, by careful "dovetailing" we can get all the true $\Pi^0_{n+1}$-sentences by stage $\omega\cdot n$, for each finite $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I am familiar with computability theory and Turing machines, but less familiar with the next step, the Turing hierarchy and the arithmetic hierarchy ; I am only vaguely aware that the $\Sigma_p^q$ and $\Pi_p^q$ are related to the $\exists$ and $\forall$ quantifiers, and your statement that my reachable sets are $\Sigma_3^0$ is as yet esoteric to me. You could probably help me out by indicating a mainstream reference explaining this in more detail.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Soare's old book ("Recursively enumerable sets and degrees") is what I learned from; [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy) is pretty decent too. Intuitively, a $\Sigma^0_3$ set has the form $\{x:\exists y\forall z\exists w\xi\}$, where $\xi$ is some "easily-checkable" condition. Here's how to see that reachability is $\Sigma^0_3$: $\varphi$ is reachable iff **there exists** some finite sequence of formulas and some proof of $\varphi$ in the corresponding extension of $T$ such that **for all** $k$ and $i$ **there is** a proof of the appropriate type.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take some time to digest all this (and accept this answer when I'm fully convinced).

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Coming back to this after a while, are there any points you'd like me to expand on?

Comment: Sorry, I'd forgotten about this question a little bit. Answer accepted now.